# Which output file from CASTEP after geometry optimization is like with the CONTCAR from VASP?

Tags: geometry-optimization, castep

I am trying to use the atomic positions in geometry optimized crystal structure to get the radial distribution function.

I know that some codes can read the positions of the atoms from the CONTCAR file (VASP), but I cannot get a similar file from CASTEP.

Can someone that works with CASTEP explain to me how to get the positions of the atoms after geometry optimization from CASTEP?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The main structural output of a geometry optimization in Castep is in the file with the ".geom" extension. That file contains blocks with lattice parameters and atomic positions at each step of a geometry optimization, and the final structure would be the last block in the file. More details about this file can be found in the Castep manual [here](https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/castep/Geom_Opt/node21.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, ProfM.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @ProfM, you can use the last step of the .geom file.

Additionally, a particularly helpful parameter that I use is `write_cell_structure`. If set to true in your .param file, then CASTEP will output a formatted cell file for you with the optimised geometry. This will include the parameters used in the calculation, e.g pseudopotential string, kpoint grid, symmetries, etc.

In your .param file, add, `write_cell_structure : true`.
The file will be named XX-out.cell with XX being your calculation prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained how to get the information from CASTEP, and you could probably also use ASE to convert the files for you, but do you really need to generate a CONTCAR? Most tools I know accept input from many DFT codes directly, including CASTEP; for example [MDANSE](https://mdanse.org/).

Even CASTEP's old [MDTEP](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/castep/MD/node19.html) tool will give you an RDF, if that's all you want, although its user interface is definitely showing its age...